# How to run a PowerShell script as a job in Jenkins

Tags: powershell, jenkins, powershell-2.0

This sounds like a simple question, but I haven't been able to work it out after looking online. I basically want to execute a PowerShell script (e.g. script.ps1) in Jenkins and report success/failure.

**Try 1:** Run following as "Execute Windows Batch Command"

```
powershell -File c:\scripts\script.ps1
```

This starts up as expected, but it quits after a few seconds.

**Try 2:** Run following as "Execute Windows Batch Command"

```
powershell -NoExit -File c:\scripts\script.ps1
```

This runs the whole script successfully, but it never stops. I had to manually abort the script.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Well, there is a [PowerShell](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/PowerShell+Plugin) plugin, which is wrapping the shell anyway. I use this on my server, executing scripts in standard notation:

```
powershell -File test001.ps1
```

It works without any quirks.

Comment: Cool, I tried the plugin but couldn't get it to run a ps1 file. But I never tried the notation above. Will try it this way, Thanks!

Comment: I used the following:

    powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File file.ps1

Comment: I can't get the plugin working properly too, probably related to execution policy or something. Had to fall back to tandard comand line  with powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -File script.ps1

Answer (score 7):

I found the problem came down to PowerShell managing the execution policy separately for 32-bit and 64-bit versions. Checkout http://www.gregorystrike.com/2011/01/27/how-to-tell-if-powershell-is-32-bit-or-64-bit/ to try launching both. Run `Get-ExecutionPolicy` in both and you will see they are different.

At least with version 1.4, it appears the plugin ends up using the 32-bit process.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the 64 bit PowerShell you don't need run the '-ExecutionPolicy Bypass':

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -nologo -file 'c:\scripts\upgrade-Chrome.ps1' -WindowStyle Hidden
```